# lambda-calc program which halts on only one input

Tags: lambda-calculus

Does there exist a normal-form lambda calculus program $f$ such that

- $f (\lambda x . x)$ normalizes
- For all normal form $e \ne \lambda x . x$, $f e$ does not normalize

Answer (score 4):

Well nevermind this has an easy answer.

Let $r_n = \lambda x_1 ... x_n . \lambda p . p \: x_1 ... x_n$

Note that for $m < n$, $r_n\: A_1 ... A_m$ normalizes for any normal $A_1 ... A_m$.

Then for any $f$, let $n$ be larger than the number of subterms in $f$.

$f \:r_n$ normalizes, so therefore no $f$ exists which only normalizes for a specific input.

Comment: Did you use the fact that $f$ normalizes on $\lambda x.\ x$? Does this actually prove that any normalizing $f$ must normalize on infinitely many normalized arguments?